# How do I use Google Domain to connect two different web services using a subdomain?

Tags: google, domains, web-hosting, dns, subdomain

I have an Adobe Portfolio site and use a Google Domain for it. Meaning my Adobe Portfolio's URL is `example.com`. I just got a website through Siteground and want to use my Google Domain for that as well, but through a Subdomain like `links.example.com` but keep my portfolio's URL as `example.com`.

Comment: Keep the DNS entry for `example.com` (sometimes listed as "@") and the DNS entry for `www.example.com` both pointed at your Adobe portfolio. Add the DNS record that Siteground wants you to for `links.example.com`. Done!

Answer (score 1):

All is about ***DNS***, so the config should be done in your google domain DNS manager if this is your case. [If your Name Servers or NS are pointed from google domains dns manager to another, you should perform the actions in the pointed NameServers DNS management]

Don't modify the root zone records of your `example.com`, sometimes came with an @ or with the full domainName.com.

So, then create an (A-AAAA)(IP[Hosting Provider{SiteGround site}]) record depending on Ipv4-Ipv6 or a CNAME (`example.com`) if this is the same as `example.com` `A` record for your Siteground routing.

**In case of `@` just use;**

Don't use `@`, instead use the desired subdomain as in the example

`A       links       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx                            TTL(As desired)` [if IPv4]
or

`AAAA    links       xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx    TTL(As desired)` [if IPv6]
or

`CNAME   links       example.com                                 TTL(As desired)` [if Same `A` or `AAA` as `example.com` siteground or other hosting provider]

**In case of `example.com` just use**

`A       links.example.com       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx                            TTL(As desired)` [if IPv4] or

`AAAA    links.example.com       xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx    TTL(As desired)` [if IPv6]

or

`CNAME   links.example.com       example.com                                 TTL(As desired)` [if Same `A` or `AAA` as `example.com` siteground or other hosting provider]

--

Remember, here we're just adding, not modifying or deleting any DNS Record.

All of these assuming that the hosting provider is already set up to receive a route from `links.example.com` which will be the subdomain and also the site to show.

Comment: They also need to set up their hosting at Siteground to expect `links.example.com`.   That is usually done by setting the domain name for the site, or by adding an "add-on domain".